# Blazor Server Multi-tenant with shared database and both host and path strategy

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side, multi-tenant, claims-based-identity

I have been researching a good way to do the following:

- Have a multi-tenant app that has a shared database. I have already implemented this, including the query filters.
- A tenant can have a host property, and if that is set, the app should use subdomains to search for the tenant. If not, then it should default to using the path strategy. (e.g., I want https://mydomain/*tenant*/ if the host is not set; otherwise, it should be https://tenant.mydomain/).
- If the host is set, I want to either block https://mydomain/*tenant*/ or redirect to the subdomain.
- Users can have different tenants with different roles on each tenant, but the roles are the same across the tenants (fx. johndoe has role guest on tenant1, but admin on tenant2).

I have looked into Finbuckle.MultiTenant but I can't find a good way to implement this mix of strategies.

I am using .NET Core Identity and EFCore, and the issue I stumbled upon creating the roles is that I can't use the UserManager to create roles that have a TenantId. Also, I am unsure how to store the claims since it would require having string concatination (fx. {role}-{tenant}).

Is there a good approach to this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are these real separate people with control over their own data?  Or is it just you separating your site into multiple apps?

Comment: These are real separate people. Each user can create/modify objects.